# VWD 2010 Express won't use default browser

Tags: internet-explorer, vwdexpress

VWD 2010E (on Win7) always uses IE9 no matter what the system default browser is.  I've tried making both Chrome and FireFox the default browser, it works with Word for instance, but VWD 2010E always uses IE9.  It was working properly in the past but now no matter what I do it is stuck on IE9.  Is there a setting somewhere that I'm missing?

Thanks,  Joe

This question concerns an ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application, not Web Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been running VWD 2010 Express as admin.  When I run as my local account VWD 2010 Express uses whatever the default browser is for my local windows account.  I haven't checked but the default browser for the windows admin account was probably different for the two different disk images.

To sum up.  VWD 2010 Express **DOES** use the default browser with MVC projects.  The default browser is for the profile of whoever VWB2010 Express is running under, not for the local windows session.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I believe that this is hardwired in VWD. You can open up the other browser to the same url after IE has opened, but I don't believe you can change the default browser in the free IDEs from MS.

Comment: I had thought VWD 2010E used whatever the system default was.  I have two disk images of my Win7 with VWD 2010E installation. One of them VWD 2010E always uses Chrome, the other VWD 2010E always uses IE.  I cannot figure what the difference is in the setup.  I tried swapping out the CurrentSettings.vssettings file between the two and it makes no difference.  Still a puzzle??

Answer (score 0):

I thought the same as vansimke, but I just tried it and successfully switched to Chrome.  FWIW, in my case it is a web site ("create new web site") vs a regular project ("create new project") so that may explain the difference.

In the Solution Explorer I right-clicked on the top entry and selected "browse with..."  There's an option there to set the choice as a default.

Comment: I should of clarified that this is with an MVC project, not a website.  With webforms you can choose a browser to run.  The same MVC project uses a different browser depending on which of my system backups I use.  I am trying to figure out what controls that and why it doesn't use the system default browser.  Again this question concerns an ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

first open asp.net webform project in your vwd2010. In that project change the vwd 2010 default browser by right click on .aspx page and choose "change default browser" option.then, open the asp.net mvc project in the vwd 2010, now u can run ur asp.net mvc project in the selected browser.

hope it helps

Comment: giri  As I said this is not a webform project, your comment does not apply.  See my answer.